# Observer not working

Tags: event-observer

I can't get an observer working, I'm using a fresh Magento install of 1.9.10.

My namespace: TM

My module: ProductConditions

app/etc/modules/TM_ProductConditions.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <TM_ProductConditions>

            <!-- Whether our module is active: true or false -->
            <active>true</active>

            <!-- Which code pool to use: core, community or local -->
            <codePool>local</codePool>

        </TM_ProductConditions>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/TM/ProductConditions/etc/config.xml:

```
<global>
    <events>                
        <catalog_product_save_before>
            <observers>
                <ProductConditions>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>TM_ProductConditions_Model</class>
                    <method>catalog_product_save_before</method>
                </ProductConditions>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_save_before>
    </events>
</global>
```

app/code/local/TM/ProductConditions/Model/Observer.php:

```
<?php
class TM_ProductConditions_Model_Observer
{
    public function catalog_product_save_before($observer)
    {
        file_put_contents("C:\\mage test.txt", "test");
        //$product = $observer->getProduct();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try 2 things. 1: change your fn() name to test($observer) and then do a die(var_dump(test)) instead of the file_put_content. Try savinf a product and see if you get to the var_dump.

Comment: I renamed my observer's method to test and stuck a var_dump in there, I did not see the output in my browser.  The AJAX request redirects the browser as normal after saving a new product.

Comment: Solved, forgot to disable the caches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
<class>TM_ProductConditions_Model</class>
```

it should be

```
<class>TM_ProductConditions_Model_Observer</class>
```

**[EDIT]**
Your observer is not picked up because the config file is wrong.
it should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <TM_ProductConditions>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </TM_ProductConditions>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <events>                
            <catalog_product_save_before>
                <observers>
                    <ProductConditions>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>TM_ProductConditions_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>catalog_product_save_before</method>
                    </ProductConditions>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_save_before>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately it didn't fix it. I will keep the _Observer at the end now.

Comment: one more thing...`config.xml` contains only what you posted or everything is wrapped up in a `<config>` tag?

Comment: config.xml only contains what I posted.

Comment: @Mex. IN that case, see my update.

Comment: Thanks again, I'm now using the config.xml you gave me, but it's still not working! :(

Comment: Found the problem, I had forgotten to disable the caches after a fresh install of Magento. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @Marius I just confused, which one is correct in the observer : <class>tm_productconditions/observer</class>
 or <class>TM_ProductConditions_Model_Observer</class>

Answer (score 3):

You don't have a complete class reference here:

```
<class>TM_ProductConditions_Model</class>
```

It should be a full class name:

```
<class>TM_ProductConditions_Model_Observer</class>
```

You can also use the abstract factory in this node.  Setup models in your config:

```
<config>
    <global>
        <models>
            <tm_productconditions>
                <class>Tm_ProductConditions_Model</class>
            </tm_productconditions>
        <models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Now you can place this in your observer:

```
<class>tm_productconditions/observer</class>
```